# Delphi synapse TTCPBlockSocket

Tags: http, sockets, delphi, post, ararat-synapse

EDIT: I need to make a POST connection with TTCPBlocksocket inside a delphi based applications script engine.

How to tell synapse where **Header** ends and **body**  (post elements) starts?  Or should i send them in different packets? Thank you !

```
begin
  Head:= TStringList.Create;
  Head.Add('GET / HTTP/1.1');           
  Head.Add('Accept: */*');
  Head.Add('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate');
  Head.Add('Host: www.google.ru');
  Head.Add('Connection: Keep-Alive');
  Head.Add(#10#13);

    body:= TStringList.Create;
  body.Add('username=adr');
  body.Add('login=adr');
  body.Add('password=adr');
  body.Add('r_password=adr');
  body.Add('submit=register');


  Socket:= TTCPBlockSocket.Create;      
  Socket.connect('108.167.137.28', '80'); 
  if (Socket.LastError <> 0) then Exit;   
  Socket.SendString(Head.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you david, i have edited the post , hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: I'v read the mcve guide,  unfortunately i cannot share the program that is needed to reproduce the error itself since it's not free.  The peace of code i have posted is just to get an idea of what i'm trying to accomplish   , and i think that my main questions are pretty clear , its basicly just how to form a http post packet , thank you for assistance!

Comment: First, your example above is wrong. A `GET` request cannot have a body, you need `POST` instead. Second, Synapse has a [`THTTPSend`](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.html) class, you should be using that for HTTP requests. Don't use `TTCPBlockSocket` directly to implement HTTP manually. In your example above, you would sent your `name=value` pairs using the `THTTPSend.HttpPostURL()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by this topic - 
[How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

> The content is put after the HTTP headers. The format of an HTTP POST
>   is to have the HTTP headers, followed by a blank line, followed by the
>   request body. The POST variables are stored as key-value pairs in the
>   body.